# Assignment chaining in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

In Java, there is a syntactic sugar construction called `assignment chaining` as shown below:

```java
public class Cat {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    Cat() {
        lastName = firstName = "Matroskin"; // compiles!
    }
}
```

Is there a way to perform exactly this in Kotlin?

Comment: No. Unlike in java, assignments in kotlin are not expressions, so this cannot be done.

Comment: yes you can do that using the init block serves the same purpose as the constructor in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works in Java because assignments are expressions that evaluate to the value that is assigned. However, assignments are not expressions in Kotlin, so the same syntax cannot be done.

If you want to avoid writing `"Matroskin"` twice, you can use one of the many [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) available. I'd use `let`:

```kotlin
"Matroskin".let {
    firstName = it
    lastName = it
}
```

Since this is in a constructor, you can also do:

```kotlin
var firstName = "Matroskin"
var lastName: String

init {
    lastName = firstName
}
```

---

(This part is for fun only)

That said, you can *technically* abuse Kotlin's features to achieve similar syntax, by defining an infix function called `=`.

```kotlin
infix fun <T> T.`=`(prop: KMutableProperty<T>): T {
    prop.setter.call(prop)
    return this
}
```

```kotlin
"Matroskin" `=` ::lastName `=` ::firstName
```

Note that the value to be assigned is ordered first, because infix functions are left associative. You could declare `=` with the arguments reversed, but then the usage needs brackets:

```kotlin
::lastName `=` (::firstName `=` "Matroskin")
```

Also, this doesn't count as initialising properties, so Kotlin will complain that `firstName` and `lastName` aren't initialised if you don't give them default values:

```kotlin
var firstName = ""
var lastName = ""
```

If you are using `val`s, then this way is not applicable.